# How to do ProxyPass to a tomcat and a static website both?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I have an apache installed on amazon linux there I have tomcat and static website and both should serve through apache.

This is my first conf file (app_name.conf)I have done proxy pass like this :--

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName example1.com

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass           /app_name http://example1.com:8080/app_name/
ProxyPassReverse    /app_name http://example1.com:8080/app_name/

</VirtualHost>
```

This proxy pass is for tomcat.

I have one static website (/var/www/example2) and confi file (example2.conf) is like this :--

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.example2.com
    ServerAlias example2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example2
    ErrorLog /var/www/example2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example2/requests.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Problem :-- Before I was having only one Virtual Host (upper one) and it was working fine but now I added one more Virtual Host.
Now I'm not able to access second Virtual host (example2.com) Its redirecting to first only.

Any Help highly appreciate !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Apache 2.2 to define several virtualhosts for the same ip:port combo, for example *:80 you need to define this directive once and in server config context:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Apache 2.2 can't distinguish between named virtualhosts if you don't define this directive. Also note this directive is only necessary/valid for 2.2.x, 2.4.x version of Apache does not need it anymore.